# I am having issues utilizing NPM commands

Tags: npm-install, npm-scripts, npm-start

Im currently trying to make a functional log in system for a company website.

This is the video im using for reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-RCnNyD0L-s&t=149s

I am unable to get NPM to work for me. i installed node.js and i installed npm by microsoft im now stuck, none of the commands are working for me.

Comment: What does it show when you type npm on your console?

Comment: Add screenshots adter running command on your terminal or cmd prompt, whatsoever u use.. that will make us understand the context better!